GTK4 rapidly display multiple frames
I am trying to display a video stream received from an ffmpeg stream.
ffmpeg -f x11grab -framerate 60 -video_size 1920x1080 -i :0.0 -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast -tune zerolatency -b:v 3M -f mpegts -pix_fmt yuv420p -flush_packets 0 -rtbufsize 1M udp://127.0.0.1:8000
I also built a C client with GTK4 that receives that stream and displays it.
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <libavformat/avformat.h>
#include <libavcodec/avcodec.h>
#include <libswscale/swscale.h>
#include "time.h"

#define WIDTH 1920
#define HEIGHT 1080

GtkWidget *image;
uint8_t* rgb_frame;

static inline unsigned char clamp(int value) {
    return value<0 ? 0 : (value>255 ? 255 : value);
}

void yuv420_to_rgb(unsigned char *y, unsigned char *u, unsigned char *v) {
    for (int j = 0; j < HEIGHT; j++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < WIDTH; i++) {
            int yIndex = j * WIDTH + i;

            int uvRow = j >> 1;
            int uvCol = i >> 1;
            int uvIndex = uvRow * (WIDTH>>1) + uvCol;

            int Y = y[yIndex];
            int U = u[uvIndex] - 128;
            int V = v[uvIndex] - 128;

            rgb_frame[3 * yIndex] = clamp(Y + (1.402 * V));     // Red
            rgb_frame[3 * yIndex + 1] = clamp(Y - (0.344136 * U) - (0.714136 * V)); // Green
            rgb_frame[3 * yIndex + 2] = clamp(Y + (1.772 * U)); // Blue
        }
    }
}

static void activate (GtkApplication *app, gpointer user_data) {
    GtkWidget *window;

    window = gtk_application_window_new (app);
    gtk_window_set_title (GTK_WINDOW (window), "Window");
    gtk_window_set_default_size (GTK_WINDOW (window), 200, 200);

    image = gtk_image_new();

    gtk_window_set_child (GTK_WINDOW (window), image);
    gtk_window_present (GTK_WINDOW (window));
}

void update(AVFrame* frame) {
    yuv420_to_rgb(frame->data[0], frame->data[1], frame->data[2]);
    GdkPixbuf *pixbuf = gdk_pixbuf_new_from_data(rgb_frame, GDK_COLORSPACE_RGB, FALSE, 8, WIDTH, HEIGHT, WIDTH * 3, NULL, NULL);
    gtk_image_set_from_pixbuf(image, pixbuf);
}

gpointer background_thread(gpointer data) {
    const char *url = "udp://127.0.0.1:8000";

    AVFormatContext *pFormatContext = avformat_alloc_context();
    if (avformat_open_input(&pFormatContext, url, NULL, NULL) != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not open input stream.\n");
        return 0;
    }

    if (avformat_find_stream_info(pFormatContext, NULL) < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not find stream info.\n");
        return 0;
    }

    int video_stream_index = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < pFormatContext->nb_streams; i++) {
        if (pFormatContext->streams[i]->codecpar->codec_type == AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO) {
            video_stream_index = i;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (video_stream_index == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not find video stream.\n");
        return 0;
    }

    AVCodecParameters *pCodecParameters = pFormatContext->streams[video_stream_index]->codecpar;
    AVCodec *pCodec = avcodec_find_decoder(pCodecParameters->codec_id);
    if (!pCodec) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Unsupported codec.\n");
        return 0;
    }

    AVCodecContext *pCodecContext = avcodec_alloc_context3(pCodec);
    avcodec_parameters_to_context(pCodecContext, pCodecParameters);
    if (avcodec_open2(pCodecContext, pCodec, NULL) < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not open codec.\n");
        return 0;
    }

    AVFrame *pFrame = av_frame_alloc();
    AVPacket packet;

    while (av_read_frame(pFormatContext, &packet) >= 0) {
        if (packet.stream_index == video_stream_index && avcodec_send_packet(pCodecContext, &packet) >= 0) {
            while (avcodec_receive_frame(pCodecContext, pFrame) >= 0) {
                update(pFrame);
            }
        }
        av_packet_unref(&packet);
    }

    av_frame_free(&pFrame);
    avcodec_free_context(&pCodecContext);
    avformat_close_input(&pFormatContext);
}

gboolean update_ui(gpointer data) {
    return GPOINTER_TO_INT(data);
}

int main (int argc, char **argv) {
    rgb_frame = malloc(WIDTH * HEIGHT * 3);
    GtkApplication *app = gtk_application_new ("org.gtk.example", G_APPLICATION_DEFAULT_FLAGS);
    g_signal_connect (app, "activate", G_CALLBACK (activate), NULL);

    GThread *thread = g_thread_new("background_thread", background_thread, update_ui);

    int status = g_application_run (G_APPLICATION (app), argc, argv);
    g_object_unref (app);

    return status;
}

I don't use GtkVideo because I want to have full control over how I draw the frames.
However, every 5 to 10 seconds the image disappears, and I get this warning:
Gtk-WARNING **: Trying to snapshot GtkApplicationWindow 0x55a549c88310 without a current allocation
Sometimes the program even crashes (SEGFAULT).
What is wrong with this code, is there another way to draw the images?

I'm not familiar with Gtk4, but I see you have av_frame_free(&pFrame);. To me it has to be av_frame_free(pFrame);. Am I wrong?

A similar thought goes exactly for avcodec_free_context(&pCodecContext); and avformat_close_input(&pFormatContext);
